# How can I return the employee names from table hr.employees who were hired on first half of the month in last month of every quarter

Tags: oracle, date-format

i need to get the employees that hired in the first half in the last month of a quarters
like i need the employees that hired from(1/3 to 15/3) and (1/6 to 15/6) same in months 9 and 12

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MONTHS_BETWEEN` and `TRUNC`:

If you want the rows where the instant of the `hire_date` is in the first half of the month of the 3rd month of the quarter then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   hr.employees
WHERE  MONTHS_BETWEEN( hire_date, TRUNC( hire_date, 'Q' ) ) BETWEEN 2 AND 2.5;
```

If you want the rows where the entirety of the day of the `hire_date` is within the first half of the month of the 3rd month of the quarter then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   employees
WHERE  MONTHS_BETWEEN(
         TRUNC( hire_date ) + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND,
         TRUNC( hire_date, 'Q' )
       ) BETWEEN 2 AND 2.5;
```

or, if you want to manually set the bounds:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   employees
WHERE  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM hire_date ) IN ( 3, 6, 9, 12 )
AND    EXTRACT( DAY FROM hire_date ) BETWEEN 1 AND 15;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=349a35485d55b97bc2b3139bbdde96cc)*

Comment: i need to get all the employees that hired in the first half at months 3 and 6 and 9 and 12
in every year

Comment: @Exclisior That is what this does; it finds the dates that are between 2 and 2.5 months from the start of the quarter containing that date. Check the db<>fiddle and you will see the dates it returns.

Comment: @Exclisior The first query returns the rows where the `hire_date` instant is in the first half of each of March, June, September and December; the second query returns the rows where the entirety of the `hire_date` day is within the first half of each of March, June, September and December. That appears to be what your requirements are asking and I am not sure what you are saying is wrong. If you have a problem with your specifications for the question then please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66975222/edit) your question to clarify it.

Comment: no that's it 
i really appreciate your help